# How to Move only the image to the left and leaving the rest at center?

Tags: html, css

I'm brand new to Web Design/Development and I have a problem.

Please could you help me to move the image (not rendered) to the left and leave all the rest at the center.

I tried looking up in W3 Schools website but for some reason i cant get this right.
Thank you

```css
body {
  background-color: #DCDCDC;
}
.center {
  width: 500px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  text-align: center;
  .left {
    position: relative;
    right: 450px;
  }
}
ul {
  list-style-position: inside;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>My Workout Website</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="C:\Users\yalokana\Desktop\style.css">
</head>
<div class="center">

  <body>
    <h1>Challenge for the next four months.</h1>
    <h3>Hello Internet! I'll introduce myself.</h3>

    <div class="left">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/200x200">
    </div>

    <p>My name is Alok and I have challenged myself.</p>
    For the next four months I want to get what i want i.e to get <strong> big and strong.</strong>
    </p>

    <p>I think to become really <strong>big and strong</strong> you need a combination of both <em>strength and endurance</em> training which I stumbled upon in <em>Brock Lesnar's</em> workout site <a href="http://theathleticbuild.com/brock-lesnar-muscle-building-and-mma-workout/"> workout routine.</a>
    </p>
    </p>
    <p>Sample of what those are have been pasted down below.</p>
    <h3>Day 1: Day1:  Chest/Triceps</h3>
    <ul>
      <li>Bench Press: 6 sets of 12 reps</li>
      <li>Incline Dumbbell Press: 4 sets of 10 reps</li>
      <li>Dumbbell Flyes: 3 sets of 8 reps</li>
      <li>Cable Crossovers: 3 sets of 8 reps</li>
      <li>Triceps Dips: 4 sets of 10 reps</li>
      <li>Triceps Pushdowns: 4 sets of 10 reps</li>
      <li>Skull Crushers: 3 sets of 10 reps</li>
    </ul>

    <p>When I'm at work I try to do as much as <em>Push-ups</em> I can, <strong>50 per set.</strong>There's also a Dip bar ground stairs and I make the best use of it!</p>
</div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: There is no need to wrap that image in a `div`, just apply the class directly to the image. And `float: left;` would work very well here.

Answer (score 1):

Your CSS is invalid:

```css
.center {
    .left { ... }
}
```

CSS does not allow us to nest selectors within other selectors, they must be separate:

```css
.center { ... }
.left { ... }
```

As images are inline, rather than trying to position them using `right`, you can instead give your `.left` element a different text alignment:

```css
.left {
    text-align: right;
}
```

```css
.left {
  text-align: right;
}
```

```html
<h1>Challenge for the next four months.</h1>
<h3>Hello Internet! I'll introduce myself.</h3>

<div class="left">
  <img src="http://placehold.it/200x200">
</div>

<p>My name is Alok and I have challenged myself.</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try like this: **[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/y9Lqoden/3/)**

CSS:

```
.center {
  width: 500px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  text-align: center;  
}
.left{
  float:left;
}
```

HTML:

```
 <div class="left">
        <img src="C:\Users\yalokana\Desktop\IMG_20150723_115150.jpg" />
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to move the image to the left of it's container - in this case it is `div.center` - you can apply to the image a [float](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/float) property. When you use float it will take the element (an image in your case) from the normal flow, the result will look like this:

[image]

If you want to place the text "My name is Alok..." below the image you should apply [clear](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/clear) property to `p` tag that contains this text. The page now looks like this:

[image]

Here's the changes I've made to your code:

HTML

```
<h3>Hello Internet! I'll introduce myself.</h3>
<img src="http://placehold.it/200x200" class="left">
<p class="clear">My name is Alok and I have challenged myself.</p>
For the next four months I want to get what i want i.e to get <strong> big and strong.</strong>
</p>
```

CSS

```
.left {
    float: left;
}
.clear {
    clear: both;
}
```

You can see full code on [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/n50ukmc6/)

Comment: I just noticed that you have opened `<p>` tag once but have closed it twice. And you've done this in two places.

Comment: Additionally you can set `margin-bottom: 10px;` to the image to create some space between the image and the text below it.

Answer (score -2):

use float left to the image class

```
 .center {
  width: 500px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  text-align: center;
  .left {
    position: relative;
    float:left
  }
}
```